# Running demucs on a bat file with drag and drop

Tags: batch-file

New to batch. Trying to set an easy way to use demucs. The bat closes as soon as it receives the anaconda activate bat command. Thanks

```
C:\Anaconda3\scripts\activate.bat
E:
cd E:\Audio Separation\demucs\
set /p "source=drag and drop file to be separated and press enter"
pause
conda activate demucs
python.exe -m demucs.separate --dl -n demucs_extra -d cpu %source%
explorer "E:\Audio Separation\demucs\separated\demucs_extra"
```

Comment: For starters, do not name you batch file `activate.bat` maybe make it `myactivate.bat`

Comment: You also do not need to do `E:` then cd to the dir, instead remove the line `E:` then do `cd /d E:\Audio Separation\demucs` Lastly, do you double click the batch file, or run it from `cmd`?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I want to click it. The batch file name is Run demucs.bat. I still can not get the bat to activate anaconda

Comment: please add pause at the end of the batch file, or run it from `cmd` so you can debug it and show me what the output is. I am assuming that cmd does not know where `conda` is. You can also open `cmd` and run `where conda` then edit your quesiton and show the results.

Comment: `@echo
cd /d E:\Audio Separation\demucs
set /p "source=drag and drop file to be separated and press enter"
call activate demucs
python.exe -m demucs.separate --dl -n demucs_extra -d cpu %source%
explorer "E:\Audio Separation\demucs\separated\demucs_extra"`

This worked. Thanks

Comment: These questions have been asked and answered before; and please don't rename `activate.bat`. You've not used the correct command to run a batch file from another. For control to return to it upon completion, you use the `Call` command. You can read its usage information by opening a Command Prompt window, typing `call /?` and pressing the `[ENTER]` key. The fix for your reported issue is to use `Call C:\Anaconda3\scripts\activate.bat`. Then as you move through your code, you should also be aware that `conda` is really `conda.bat`, and therefore requires the same treatment, `Call conda.bat …`.